# Granting roles and privileges in Oracle - should I use procedures or functions?

Tags: oracle, plsql, privileges, sql-grant

I have to automate as much of my code as possible. I have created some users, and now i need to create roles to assign to the users and grant privileges. Can I use functions for this, or is it best to use procedures? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Is there something that you will need to return after the grant is complete? If not, why would you want to use a function? A procedure simply returns control to the caller, implying success. A function is used if there is something that is resultant of the operations inside your code that you will then consume.

Comment: I want to create a role, and then assign it to a user based on their access grade, either 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: I've worked in a system with similar issue. @helpc is right you don't need anything to be returned so you can go for a procedure. It should be ok.

Comment: Ok thanks @Jorge Campos, however i have to have a function somewhere in my code while giving access rights etc, so how i could i incorporate a function in to grant privileges?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_create_roles IS
    BEGIN
    CREATE ROLE admin_staff;
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON admin_staff;
    END;
    /

Comment: this give me error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with

Comment: that error is because the user you are using to create the role doesn't have privileges to it,

Comment: would adding in AUTHID CURRENT_USER allow it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly code DDL statements such as CREATE USER or GRANT in a PL/SQL procedure. Instead, you should use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, as in

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_CREATE_ROLES IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE ROLE ADMIN_STAFF';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON BLAH TO ADMIN_STAFF';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON BLORT TO ADMIN_STAFF';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON YADA TO ADMIN_STAFF';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ADMIN_STAFF TO USER1, USER2, USER3';
END PROC_CREATE_ROLES;
```

Share and enjoy.

## EDIT

In my opinion it's better to use a procedure here.

Best of luck.

Comment: A very valid point, but not the question at hand. The poster is asking whether procedures or functions are better suited when doing this kind of operation. Good code example for general knowledge, though; short sweet and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a procedure, probably inside a 'UTILITIES' or 'USER_MANAGEMENT' package. The choice for procedure is because a procedure doesn't need to return anything. A function will always have some value to return to the caller. Use a procedure when:

- You want to perform some predefined actions
- You do not want to return a value directly

Use a function when:

- You want to perform a calculation, or get a return value of some sort

Functions can also be used from inside SQL, while procedures are called from a separate BEGIN/END block.

Answer (score 0):

Use procedures and make sure they are owned by an account that has the required privileged directly granted. Doing so makes your application more secure because you don't need to logon with a dba (or similar) account. Don't forget to add logging and auditing.